# How downloading file in small chunks on different threads increase the download speed?

Tags: android, multithreading, download-manager

I am thinking of making a download manager for Android.One of the functionality I want is to Download a file in small chunks on different threads for increasing download speed.I want to know how can this increase download speed and in how many parts to divide the file in.

Comment: It doesn't. It just adds connection setup and teardown overhead.

Comment: You need to know that whatever server you are requesting a file needs to have the capability to upload a file to a user starting from different positions. If not, it isn't worth.